# Issues with putExtra and getStringExtra

Tags: android

I just started to learn Android application development. I am working out on the example in android tutorial from the site http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

While sending the text from my `MyActivity` page to `DiplayMessageActivity`,

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

is returning null as value.

Here is the code for my `sendMessage()`,

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE",message);
    String message1 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

To the extent, I can read about `putExtra` and `getStringExtra()` methods, I did, but I could not resolve the issue. I may missing very tiny thing but couldn't trace out.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Why are you trying to put and get in the same activity? For your error, you are not using same KEY to put and get, thats why it is not working.

Comment: `String message1 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);` should be in `DisplayMessageActivity.class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this:

```
String message1 = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
```

here you are using `EXTRA_MESSAGE` as `Constant` in `getStringExtra` and `String` Literal in `putExtra`. So either use Literal or as `Constant` Name.

Comment: Welcome, if this solves your issue, your upvote or mark as accepted answer encourage us. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `String message1 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);`
use `String message1 = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);`

Answer (score 0):

**For Sending info use like below**

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE",message);
startActivity(intent);
```

}

**Get this message in DisplayMessageActivity.class like below**

```
Intent in=getIntent();
String message1 = in.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
```

Answer (score -1):

check that when you put "EXTRA_MESSAGE" in intent then you are using different constant may be MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE is having different value

Comment: Do not add same answer, if it is already added by someone else.

Comment: Thank you for your response, why are you being offensive? I was on the same page, and know the time difference was more than 2 minutes. Be gentle!! I understand you are new here, and it will take time to learn  to give respect to fellow members. Happy Coding.

Comment: yes i know but when i was editing then i at the same time i can't able to watch the comment of other and that is not my mistake. but sorry about my behaviour sir.